# Is there a way to inherits table which is not owned by current user

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

I create two users in my PostgreSQL db. let's say `migration` and `dev`.

I create a table `A` with user `migration`. Then I create table `B` which inherits table `A` as user `dev`, but that fails.

```
ERROR:  must be owner of relation A
```

If I don't want to alter the table owner, is there another way to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use a role of which both users are members:

```
CREATE ROLE tab_owner NOLOGIN NOINHERIT;

GRANT tab_owner TO dev, migration;
```

Now when `migration` creates a table, it first runs:

```
SET ROLE tab_owner;
```

Then the table is owned by the role.

User `dev` does the same thing before creating an inheritance child of the table.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe, Actually I simplify the use case in my question, the real case is: I want to use partition table by inheritance. so I create and automatic trigger for insert operation, when insert data row, it will auto create child table by created time, and it failed due to above reason, that's why I create this question. After I do some investigation, I've resolved it use SECURITY DEFINER.

Comment: Use a trigger function owned by the table owner and define it as `SECURITY DEFINER`. Don't forget `SET search_path = pg_catalog` in the function declaration.

Comment: Actually I'm confused about this search_path, I see the doc mentioned this, and I'm not quite sure what it used to, currently I set it like this: `SET search_path = public, pg_temp;` is there any problem here?

Comment: Sorry for being too terse, I was referring to [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) important warning about `SECURITY DEFINER` functions in the documentation.

Comment: I also read this part, search_path is set to `admin, pg_temp` in the example, and `pg_catalog` in your comment, if my table A and table B is belong to public schema, should i set search_path to `public, pg_temp`? I'm just not quite understand how it works..

Comment: It should never contain `public` unless you revoke the `CREATE` privilege on that schema. The safest way is to use `pg_catalog` like I said and qualify all access to objects in the function with the schema.

Comment: Which means the tables can only be accessed like: `pg_catalog.A` `pg_catalog.B` ?

Comment: Yes, precisely.